# Runtime error when executing simple closure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, closures, higher-order-functions

Im new to JS and trying to learn. The spec requires the following: 
Write a function that takes another function* as an argument and creates a version of the function that can only be called one time. Repeated calls to the modified function will have no effect, returning the value from the original call. How could you do this without using a closure? Is it even possible? How could you do this with a closure? *Note: This original input function should not have any parameters.

This is what I have:

```
var divide = function () {
var x = 2;
var y = 6;

return y/x;
}

var mainFunc = function (func) {
return func(){
    return y/x + 1;
}
}

var output = mainFunc(divide);
console.log(divide());
console.log(output());
console.log(output());
```

I'm getting an "Unexpected token{" error at "return func(){" I don't quite understand what i'm doing wrong? Per the spec, I am passing divide() to mainFunc() and setting it to a reference variable output. I then call the divide() and output() multiple times to test if the closure works and that modified function only happens once. What am I missing or not understanding?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: return func(){  //this is a syntax error, and { is the unexpected token here

Comment: how is a syntax error? I am passing divide() into mainFunc(), so func() should take on the properties of divide, right?

Comment: Perhaps it might be of help if you explain what you *exactly* wanted to achieve. In words, not in code.

Comment: Well, I want to acheive what the spec is requiring -- Writing a function that takes a function as an argument and creates a version that can only be called once. The original function should not have any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
function runonce(func) {
  return (function(func) {
    var ran = false;
    var retval;
    return function() {
      if (!ran) {
        ran = true;
        retval = func();
      }
      return retval;
    }
  })(func);
}

function realfunction() {
  console.log('really running');
  return 5;
}

var realfunctionrunner = runonce(realfunction);
realfunctionrunner();
realfunctionrunner();
realfunctionrunner();
```

Study the code, the whole trick is a "self contained library" which result is returned from the runonce function